# New tag for Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: feature-request

I have a question about my Ask Ubuntu post: [FATAL -> Failed to fork on Windows subsystem for Linux with Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1054464/fatal-failed-to-fork-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux-with-ubuntu)

Hi

Is it possible to create a new tag about the Windows Subsystem for Linux, something like windows-subsystem-for-linux for example?

Kind Regards

Comment: I closed this as a duplicate since the duplicate essentially answers your question: there is such a tag an dit ha now been added to your post.

Answer (score 1):

We already have a tag for that, it’s called [windows-subsystem-for-linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/windows-subsystem-for-linux). I tagged your question accordingly.